# Optimal configuration for both development and distribution stages of the nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I want to produce a set of NuGet packages written in C#.

These packages are class libraries, referencing each other in the way like:

- MyGreatPackage.Core - no references
- MyGreatPackage.Feature1 - references the core
- MyGreatPackage.Feature2 - also references the core
- MyGreatPackage.Feature2.SubFeature1 - references the Feature2 package and, respectively, the core

During the development stage, there is often a lack of real-world use-cases, so I decided to develop those packages as a part of a real project.
To implement it, I extract those packages as a git submodule(s) and connect them to the repository of the main application.

As a result, there is a .net solution like that:

- MyApp.sln
- MyApp.Host.csproj
- MyApp.ClassLibrary1.csproj - references MyGreatPackage.Core.csproj
- MyGreatPackage.Core.csproj - in the submodule
- MyGreatPackage.Feature1.csproj - in the submodule, references MyGreatPackage.Core.csproj
- MyGreatPackage.Feature2.csproj (references the core csproj)
- MyGreatPackage.Feature1.SubFeature1.csproj (references the feature1 csproj)

Everything goes smoothly here, as I can develop both the app and the packages.

But, when it comes to the distribution stage, this configuration doesn't seem to work, as I can't simply push the submodule contents to the NuGet and replace the submodule references with the NuGet references.

The problem is that the Feature1 package when prepared for pushing to the NuGet, should have a reference to the MyGreatPackage.Core package and not a reference to the csproj. Also, the Feature2 package and subfeature1 package.

So how should I prepare this setup for both the development and the distribution stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a trivial answer to your question. But here are some possibilities:

- Use some kind of tool that easily allows you to switch between project references (for working locally, being able to easily debug code, etc.) and NuGet references (for publishing your applications). [RicoSuter/DNT](https://github.com/RicoSuter/DNT) has a [switch-to-projects](https://github.com/RicoSuter/DNT#switch-to-projects) command that does exactly this.
- Always use NuGet package references, and publish new versions whenever you need it: either to a local or to a private NuGet feed. You can debug NuGet packages with the use of tools like [SourceLink](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink), or punctually include projects. Depending how tightly coupled your projects are and the stage of development you're at, this option can be more or less viable.
- The poor's man alternative to the first one when using the second approach: having a git stash that includes those projects in the solution and replaces the NuGet references with the project ones. If you work on your own, this can be an option to sporadically change to project references and debug something. If used often, this can be a pain due to those change being accidentally commited, etc.